# Creating subset using or statement

Tags: julia, subset, boolean-operations

I have a data frame with 6 columns and thousands of rows containing share transactions. I want to identify rows with bad price data. The following function gives me a subset with the rows with good price data:

```
function in_price_range(df)
    price_good = subset(df, :UnitPrice => X-> (trough_share_price .<= X .<= peak_share_price), skipmissing=true)
    return price_good
end
```

For a subset for bad data I tried:

```
function out_price_range(df)
    price_discrepancy = subset(df, :UnitPrice => X-> (X .< trough_share_price || X .> peak_share_price), skipmissing=true)
    return price_discrepancy
end
```

However, that givers error *TypeError: non-boolean (BitVector) used in boolean context*

I tried .|| rather than || but that then gives error: *syntax: "|" is not a unary operator*

How do I fix the code?

Answer (score 1):

In Julia, `||` is

```
help?> ||
search: ||

  x || y

  Short-circuiting boolean OR.
```

The short-circuiting part meaning, that if `x` is true, `||` will not even bother to evaluate `y`. In other words, this will make a *branch* in the code. For example:

```
julia> 5 < 7 || print("This is unreachable")
true
```

This is great if you want to write code that is efficient for a case like

```
if something_easy_to_evaluate || something_costly_to_evaluate
    # Do something
end
```

In other words, this is control flow! Obviously, this cannot be broadcasted. For that, what you want is the regular `or` operator `|`, which you can broadcast with `.|`. So for example:

```
julia> a = rand(3) .< 0.5
3-element BitVector:
 1
 0
 0

julia> b = rand(3) .< 0.5
3-element BitVector:
 0
 1
 0

julia> a .|| b
ERROR: syntax: "|" is not a unary operator
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ none:1

julia> a .| b
3-element BitVector:
 1
 1
 0
```

The same applies to `&&` vs `&`; the former is only used for control-flow, the latter is normal bitwise `and`.

Comment: In Julia 1.7 `.||` will be allowed, see https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/39594. Still in this case I think `.|` is preferred.

Comment: TIL! __________